# davinci resolve Editing subtitles at the same time as the video

Tags: davinci-resolve, subtitles

I used a program to auto-generate the subtitles srt to a video which I'm putting in the timeline. I want to edit the video on the edit page, doing ripple deletes. But when I do a cut and a ripple delete the subtitle doesn't follow, only the video and audio gets edited. How can I edit it all together? The idea is that when I make ripple edits to the video timeline the subs should be automatically retimed.

Comment: It works for me in R17.1. Since you generated the SRTs outside, I’d suspect however you’ve applied them. What happens when you build subtitles from scratch by right-clicking in the track header, selecting “add subtitle track” and then adding some by hand? Will those follow a ripple delete?

Comment: Have you tried linking them to the audio and video (Ctrl-Alt-L)?